# Disabling Domain User Account Using Python - Active Directory Integration

Tags: python, dns, active-directory, user-accounts, account-management

I'm working on an organization tool in Python and need assistance with disabling a domain user account. I've explored the pyad library, but I'm unsure about the correct approach. How can I programmatically disable a domain user account in Active Directory using Python? Any guidance or code examples would be appreciated. Thank you!

I attempted to disable a domain user account using the pyad library in Python. I expected the user account to be disabled in Active Directory, but encountered an error.

Comment: You wrote (in your question): _I attempted to disable a domain user account using the pyad library in Python ... , but encountered an error._ Perhaps you can [edit] your question and post the code that you tried along with details of the error that you encountered?